# When did "Musaf Rashi" on Talmud Bavli begin being added to the on the page? Did Tosafos ever refer to any of the Musafim?

Tags: rashi, talmud-bavli, rishonim

On some editions of Talmud Bavli, there is a section entitled, "Musaf Rashi." When were these additions to his commentary found, and are there any references to it in Tosafos?

Comment: Can you identify a specific publication that includes these? Perhaps include the image of one such page?

Comment: This adition ,i think , is just a compilation of other places where Rashi talks about the topic.

Comment: FWIW, I have Gemarot from about 30 years ago, andn they don't have this. I first noticed this about 15 years ago, so it seems quite recent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mosef Rashi is a modern invention from printers who collect Rashi's writing from other Masechtos which would add insight to the sugya at hand.

As such they are Rashi's own words (or Rashbam or the like when quoting from certain masechtos) but not any new found work of his. It's the same old Rashi. So if Tosafos have anything to say about, it would usually be on the folio the are gleaned from.

Other printers have made similar works called Likutei Rashi.

Comment: yeah I think I might have heard that before